# python write if in for and return true/false in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code that checks if a string is in a list of strings like,

```
    for a in array:
        if x in a:
            return True
    return False
```

if a string is found in the list, return `True` and `False` otherwise. I am wondering if it can be written in one line of code.

Comment: `return any(x in a for a in array)`

Comment: @khelwood it is not a comment actually, you should post it as an answer I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to iterate through a sequence and see if any item matches some particular condition.

```
return any(x in a for a in array)
```